# Another Verify the identity: $\sec^2 \frac{x}{2} = \frac{2}{1+\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry

Another Verify the identity that I can't get:

$$\sec^2 \frac{x}{2} = \frac{2}{1+\cos x}$$

$$ = \frac{1 + \left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)}{2}$$

$$ = \frac{\cos x + 1}{2 \cos x}$$

Comment: This is confusing. $(\sec^2x)/2$ or $\sec^2{x/2}$?

Comment: It's the second one. sec^2 (x/2)

Comment: Sorry, just changed the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, both ways are possible :

Going backwards (which is simpler, coincidentally)

$$\frac{2}{1 + \cos x} = \frac{2}{1 + (2\cos^2\frac{x}{2} - 1)}\\
= \frac{2}{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}\\
= \sec^2\frac{x}{2}$$

---

Going forward, start by rewriting as:

$$\sec^2\frac{x}{2} = \frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}$$

By the double angle formula for $\cos$, $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta - 1$ we have (by letting $\theta = \frac{x}{2}$):

$$\cos x = 2\cos^2\frac{x}{2} - 1$$

Rearrange to get
$$\cos^2\frac{x}{2} = \frac{1 + \cos x}{2}$$

Simply substitute this back, to deduce

$$\sec^2\frac{x}{2} = \frac{1}{\frac{1 + \cos x}{2}} = \frac{2}{1 + \cos x}$$

---

It's probably worth mentioning that both approaches are equivalent, differing only by which direction you choose to prove the identity.

Comment: Awesome!  You're the man!  I've learned a lot from you!

Comment: @KKendall No problem! Back in my days (actually, just a year ago), our teachers gave us countless drills on trigo questions (in fact, questions on probably all other topics as well). I've probably seen this approach somewhere, so the problem really is familiar to me.